# Django | get_actuacion() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, django-models

Al crear una actuación en formulario admin, me devuelve el siguiente error. ¿Qué sucede?

Error:

```
TypeError at /admin/actuacion/actuacion/

get_actuacion() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Archivo `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Actuacion
from .models import TipoActuacion
from .models import TipoFallo

class ActuacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('resumen_actuacion', 'get_actuacion')
    def get_actuacion(self):    
        return ", ".join([actuacion.name for actuacion in self.object.actuacion.all()])

admin.site.register(Actuacion,ActuacionAdmin)

class TipoFalloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )
admin.site.register(TipoFallo,TipoFalloAdmin)

class TipoActuacionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'name',
    )
admin.site.register(TipoActuacion,TipoActuacionAdmin)
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from dispositivo.models import Dispositivo
from consumible.models import Consumible
from incidencia.models import Incidencia


class TipoActuacion(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo actuación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipos de actuaciones'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TipoFallo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Tipo Fallo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tipos de fallo'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Actuacion(models.Model):
    fecha_actuacion = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha actuación',null=True, blank=True)
    incidencia = models.ForeignKey(Incidencia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    dispositivo_afectado = models.ForeignKey(Dispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    fallo = models.ManyToManyField(TipoFallo)
    actuacion = models.ManyToManyField(TipoActuacion)
    SOLUCIONADO_TYPE = (
        ('0','Sin solucionar'),
        ('1','Solucionado'),
        ('2','Parcialmente solucionado'),
        ('3','En observación'),
    )
    solucionado = models.CharField('Solucionado', max_length=50, choices=SOLUCIONADO_TYPE,null=True)
    resumen_actuacion = models.TextField('Resumen',null=True, blank=True)
    detalle_actuacion = models.TextField('Observaciones',null=True, blank=True)

    class meta:
        verbose_name = 'Incidencia'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Incidencias'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resumen_actuacion
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque el método `get_actuacion` debe recibir un argumento, que es la instancia del modelo (adicional al `self`), entonces tu método debería ser así:

```
def get_actuacion(self, obj):    
    return ", ".join([actuacion.name for actuacion in obj.actuacion.all()])
```

Esto y mas se explica en la documentación de Django sobre [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), (ademas de varias maneras de hacerlo).

Por otra parte, lo puedes hacer así:

> ```
> def get_actuacion(self, obj):
>     return ", ".join(obj.actuacion.values_list('name', flat=True))
> ```
>
> La consulta SQL generada es mas rápida, ya que solo obtenemos la
> columna `name`, la consulta SQL debería ser algo así:
>
> ```
> SELECT "appname_actuacion"."name" FROM "appname_actuacion" WHERE ...
> ```
>
> En cambio con `obj.actuacion.all()` estamos obteniendo todas las
> columnas.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias Julio Cesar. No se cómo agradecerte. Agradezco la referencia a la documentación. ; )

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte broda xd